# Interpreting cost data in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I host a basic web app on Google Cloud Platform, and I've noticed my costs creeping up over the last couple of months. It's really accelerated over the last 30 days (fortunately, on a tiny base - I'm still ticking along at under $2 a day). I haven't added any new functionality or clients in months so this was a bit surprising.

[image: Cost]

My first instinct was an increase in traffic. I couldn't see anything like that in the App Engine dashboard, but I put in a heap of optimizations and dramatically decreased QPS just in case. No change.

[image: QPS drop]

The number of instances hasn't moved around much either - this looks like the most likely culprit but it's still just flat, not growing.

[image: Number of instances]

My next guess was that data was accumulating in Datastore (even though the cost chart is filtered to App Engine only, I figured a fuller datastore -> a slower datastore -> more instance time in GAE). There's no chart for this, annoyingly, but I determined the data store size was more or less flat (I have a blunt instrument TTL job that runs daily) and culled it by dropping my retention threshold by 20% just to be safe.

These optimizations were on the 17th, but my cost hasn't moved at all. I considered forex fluctuations (I'm billed in Aussie dollars, all my charges are for frontend instances in Japan) but they haven't been anywhere near big enough to explain this.

Any ideas what's going on? I've clicked through all the graphs and reports in billing but can't reconcile the ~100% growth in cost with a flat or dropping qps, instance count and database size.

Comment: I recommend you fill a case to the GCP support in order that they explain you you what happened  since we don't have so much visibility about your App engine instances and other services :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I've seen the same thing on a simple App Engine website running Python 3.7! I've had a ticket open since April 29th and they're not helpful. I saw a step change in frontend instance hours on March 24th with no corresponding increase in traffic. I have screenshots that are really telling but I can't upload them since I don't have 10 reputation points.

There's no corresponding increase in traffic, either in the cloud console or in Google analytics.

What's worse, each day the daily estimate shows I'm be under the 28 hour quota. For example, I took a screenshot that showed after 15 hours I was on pace for 24.352 frontend instance hours for the day (I didn't take one at the end of the quota day since it resets at 3AM)

When I woke up the next morning the billing report showed I was charged $0.00 for frontend instance hours for the previous day, but 3 hours later it shot up to $0.48, which means I used 38.6 frontend instance hours worth.

Somehow, the estimated cost calculation was off by 14 hours. Why have the estimate at all if it has an error that large? When I looked at the minute-by-minute billed instance hours for the hours after taking the screenshot through the end of the quota-day, there's nothing that indicates I would have used 23 additional hours from the time I took the screenshot to the time of the quota reset.

This behavior has been happening every day since March 24th for me with no explanation from Google besides "it looks like you exceeded your instances..." I wish I could share the screenshots so you can compare what you're seeing.